# ScrollTop wont work on object

Tags: javascript, jquery

`scrollTop` Won't work at all

im Trying to set a pinned Position for the Scroll bar on the Object.

This is the javascript/jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click', "button#switch", function() {

    $( "object").attr('data',  "http://AnimeAddiction.net").hide().show(); 
    $( "object").scrollTop(200);

 });        
})
```

and this is my html code

```
<object type="text/html" height="427" width="700"  data="http://www.runelocus.com">
</object>   

<button id="switch">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: `"object"` doesn't have a `.` or `#` for selecting.  Does this element have a class or an id?

Comment: Worked for me in this http://jsfiddle.net/SwhFZ/.

Comment: `$( "object").attr('data',  "http://AnimeAddiction.net").hide().show();` Works so it should still work right?

Comment: i need to make the object Scroll down, loading a new webpage works perfect what i need is to make it Scroll to a certian point on the new webpage, Right now it sits at the top left untell you move, it in the future i wanna remove the scrollbars and have it pinned to where i want it

Answer (score 1):

probably what you are trying to scroll is the document viewport `$(document).scrollTop(200)` instead of the object.

Is that the issue? or you can scroll the viewport 200px after the object:

```
$(document).scrollTop(200 + $('object').offset().top);
```

Is that the issue?

Comment: i want to scroll the webpage inside the object element

Comment: Try this: `$(document).scrollTop(200 + $('object').offset().top);`

Comment: it scrolls my website not the object element